# Is there a way to retrieve data from a hard drive that was initialised but where no simple volume was created?

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, gpt

I switched enclosures for my 3.5 inch external hard drive; the drive is a Western Digital. There after the disk showed up in Disk Management but first needed initializing. I used the GPT initializing then it asked me if I wanted to create a new simple volume but I did not proceed to create a new simple volume.

Is there any way to recover all my data from the hard drive since I didn’t create a new simple volume?

Comment: when you create a new simple volume your data will still be there

Comment: i had divided it into 3partitions but now its showing as 1block @UğurGümüşhan

Comment: Please add more details (make, model) on the disk and the enclosure.

Comment: the disk is a Western Digital drive,2TB,the other enclosure's tags were removed a while back i dont remmber its name.

Comment: It's unusual that the drive will need initializing if you only change the enclosure. You have either damaged the HDD during the move or the original enclosure was using hardware encryption and this is way the data isn't readable without the enclosure to decrypt it.  If this is the case you won't be able to retrieve anything back. Do you know if the original enclosure was a WD one?

Comment: Yes the original was a WD one, it had a faulty power plug of which i cant seem to get a replacement but will try fixing it. @Techpumpkin_WD

Comment: Most of WD external HDDs have hardware encryption, and the data cannot be read without the enclosure. This is why you were prompted to initialize the HDD when you connected it via SATA. Having in mind that you have already re initialized the HDD and the enclosure is damaged the best chance of recovering data would be to send it to a data recovery company. You can check the list of WD recovery partners here: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=PA3ZtY

Comment: I think I may have found a way to power up the hard drive using the old enclosure. if i do do i still have a chance of recovering my data by myself? @Techpumpkin_WD

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to do it. If the HDD wasn't initialized it should have been as easy as just putting it into the enclosure. But while initializing the information on the HDD has been re-written and there is no way to restore it to it's previous condition at this point. I guess you can try plugging it in the enclosure and running data recovery software, but it's a long shot. I'm afraid that at this point I can only see data recovery services as a working option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've created a new partition table on a disk that you'd used before and now you want to recover the old data on the disk. If so, your best bet is to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or something similar. TestDisk scans disks for existing filesystems and creates partitions to match those filesystems.

Creating a partition semi-randomly might work, since partitions usually begin on sector 2048, so a new partition will *probably* match the old one. This is potentially very dangerous, though, particularly if you're not intimately familiar with the tools you use. The biggest danger is that creating a new partition with a standard disk partitioning tool will also create a new filesystem in that new partition. The new filesystem's data structures will overwrite the old filesystem's data structures, making it *much* harder to recover your old data. TestDisk doesn't do this; it creates *only* the partition data structures, and it creates them to match the old filesystem(s) it finds.